# Basic Angular ng

Tags: angular, scullyio

I'm trying to get scullyio to work on a real basic ng new build. Out of the box skeleton. Steps as follows -

Installed @angular/cli.
Ran ng new scully  
Ran ng build --prod
Ran npm run scully

but continually get:

```
> scully@0.0.0 scully
> npx scully --

logging with severity "warning"
using plugins from folder "./scully"
Typescript error while compiling plugins. the error is:
error TS5042: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line.

undefined
```

Here are my versions of pretty much everything - I tried this early with @PWA, but that didn't give any luck so I start again without.

```
NPM: 7.10.0
Angular CLI: 11.2.9
Node: 15.14.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.9
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.9
@angular/cli                    11.2.9
@schematics/angular             11.2.9
@schematics/update              0.1102.9
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.1.5
```

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards,

Bretta

Answer (score 1):

If you're still running into this issue, [someone mentioned a fix for it on Scully's Github repo](https://github.com/scullyio/scully/issues/1108#issuecomment-879828845). I had the same problem, followed the fix, and it worked.

In `node_modules/@scullyio/scully/src/lib/utils/compileConfig.js` look for this line:

```js
 exec(`npx tsc -p ${configPath}`, (err, res) => {
```

and change it to:

```js
exec(`npx tsc -p "${configPath}"`, (err, res) => {
```

The change here is that `${configPath}` is now surrounded in double quotes like so `"${configPath}"`.

This is a problem Windows and Ubuntu users are having.